# How to use koin for Service

Tags: android, kotlin, koin, android-service-binding

I was starting the foreground service by manually binding and then using its method.

However, I recently came across Koin and found https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun App(myService: MyService = koinInject()) {
}
```

Now, This gave me the idea that Koin would do the binding for me, and I'll be able to use the method of the Service directly without binding and unbinding of service using `ServiceConnection`

But, I get,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: class name is null
```

On startForeground call inside service.

and,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

On, any super member call.

Now, either *I'm not properly setting up Koin*, or Koin doesn't support `Service` (*even if I manually bind it, **but** use the service instance from Koin it still crashes with the same issue*).

I'd like experts' opinions here, cuz the docs mention MyService, but not being able to use SuperClass 'Service' member seems like that was a poor choice for a class name.

Comment: Koin won't handle the Android Service lifecycle or starting a foreground service for you. You'll still need to handle those aspects yourself.

Comment: @Polarcode I've tested just now and edited the op, please check
`
(even if I manually bind it, but use the service instance from Koin it still crashes with the same issue)`

Comment: The example of `MyService` in koin docs is not an  android service, its a service that holds business logic. You can bind your android service in just a traditional way.

Comment: @AsadMahmood Are you sure? (I had the same feeling actually)

However, if you're sure then you can post it as an answer. And in the meantime, I'll try to raise an issue in their GitHub to update the docs and see what they have to say.

Comment: @CyberAvater yup 100 % sure! And you don't need to raise an issue as `service`, `usecases` are interchangeable  names for domain layer class that holds business logic in clean architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example of `MyService` in [koin docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-compose/compose/) is not an android service, its a service that holds business logic. `service`, `usecases` are interchangeable names for domain layer class that holds business logic in clean architecture. You can bind your android service in just a traditional way.

Comment: I'm taking is as the accepted answer, unless they say otherwise.
https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1626

Answer (score 0):

Koin won't handle the Android Service lifecycle or starting a foreground service for you. You'll still need to handle those aspects yourself.

Example of how you can use Koin for dependency injection with your foreground service:

Setup the koin module

```
val myModule = module {
    single { MyService() } // Replace MyService() with your actual implementation of the service
}
```

Initialize Koin in your Application class

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    startKoin {
        androidContext(this@MyApplication)
        modules(myModule) // Define your Koin modules here
    }
}
```

}

Your Gradle

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-compose:$koin_version" // If you're using Koin with Compose
```

In your Composable function, you can inject the service using koin.get() and use it directly

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val myService: MyService = koin.get() // Inject the service

    // Use myService methods here
}
```

Remember that Koin doesn't handle the lifecycle of Android components like Activities or Services. You need to start and stop your service explicitly, either manually or through other components (e.g., Activities, BroadcastReceivers).

Comment: To `Initialize Koin in your Application class` step I've done exactly the same.

now in your next step,
you're injecting MyService in MyForegroundService, 
private val myService: MyService by inject()

but in my case, MyService is the Foreground service!

And I tried injecting it directly into a composable

@Composable
fun App(myService: MyService = koinInject()) {
}

Comment: Make sure you run your application with the custom class, in my case above I used `MyApplication`.

Comment: Make sure `MyService` is initialized properly. If it requires any context or dependencies during initialization, make sure they are provided in the Koin module.